# Passing JWT in headers with axios

Tags: http-headers, axios

I've created a small project with a node back-end and react front-end to fetch the data through REST calls. I used **Axios** library, but when I pass the headers with it I keep getting an error saying:

**`Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 401 (Unauthorized)`**.

I found out two methods and both did not work. They are:

```
export const getUsersDetails=()=>{
  console.log('calling');
  return (dispatch) => {
    return axios.get('http://localhost:3030/users',{headers: { "Authorization": localStorage.getItem('jwtToken') }}).then((data)=>{
                 console.log('data comming',data);
                dispatch(getUsersData(data));
            }).catch((error)=>{
              console.log('error comming',error);
                dispatch(errorgetUsersData(error));
            });
        };
}
```

and

```
axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = localStorage.getItem('jwtToken');
```

**But When I use postman I am getting the required data from the backend**. Any particular reason why I keep getting this Unauthorized error?.

Comment: JWT stands for **J**SON **W**eb **T**oken. When you use a variable name `jwtToken`, it practically reads like *JSON Web Token Token*. I'd suggest to omit the redundancy and use just `jwt` (or maybe some other non-redundant name).

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You need to concatenate 'Bearer ' before the token, like this:

```
axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 
                                'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('jwtToken');
```

Comment: Here it only worked with `axios.defaults.headers.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('jwtToken');`. Btw, I'm using Vue and I placed it into `main.js`.

Comment: hello  Fusseldieb or dplaza or  Clonkex could you update the code.. I don't understand where put it: axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] =  'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('jwtToken'); Sorry.. I'm getting the same problem