# Best way to config Global Headers for Get, Post, Patch in VueJS

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js

I'm new with VueJs, I'm finding best way to config Global Headers for Get, Post, Patch in VueJS, which is **easy to use and strong security**. In the current I just write it in `export default {}` for every components and it's very bad I know. So I ask you guys to help.

Fixed Thanks to @Hardik Satasiya

~/plugins/axios.js

Every Components:

```
import axios from 'axios'

var api = axios.create({
  baseURL: 'http://localhost:8000/api/v1/',
  headers: {'Authorization': 'JWT ' + store.state.token}
})

export default api
```

Issues: Can't tranmit store in to axios.create, so `store is not defined`

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Yes its good idea to use `axios` because its repo is maintained.

you can use global config for this

```
import axios from 'axios';

axios.defaults.baseURL = 'https://api.example.com';
axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = AUTH_TOKEN;
axios.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded';
```

> OR **best** way is to create separate `instances` for this (if you are using `multiple api` at same time)

```
import axios from 'axios';

var myApi = axios.create({
  baseURL: 'https://my-domain.com/api/',
  timeout: 1000,
  headers: {'X-Custom-Header': 'CustomHeader1'}
});

// another api service
var amazonApi = axios.create({
  baseURL: 'https://amazon-domain.com/api/',
  timeout: 2000,
  headers: {'X-Custom-Header': 'CustomHeader2'}
});

export default {
    myApi,
    amazonApi
}
```

so you can use `api` separately without any conflict.

> if you are setting auth header it's nice to not set it at instance creation instead you can set it in your `ready callback` so you can either fetch from `localStorage` or obtain from the third party and you can set it.

to change header afterward after creation

```
myApi.defaults.headers.authorization = 'JWT ' + yourToken;
```

so you can set header from any part when you are sure you have token then you can use this code to set header.
And if you have header already from begging you can also use this code to set it.

Comment: Thank you @Hardik Satasiya. Best answer for you!

Comment: glad, you liked it :)

Comment: Excuse me, Can you show me how to get **Token in Store** or **Token in LocalStorage in your code**?

Comment: can you describe in more detail, means you need to add token to created instance after its created right ?

Comment: I fixed my code above and issues. You can take a look :)

Comment: ok added update, you can set header again when you get token for that instance.

Comment: Could I import it directly to axios.create?

Comment: yes but you need to have it from the begging then only you can import, other wise you have to add it later.

Answer (score 2):

> ON YOUR MAIN.JS

```
import axios from "axios";
const base = axios.create({
  baseURL: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/", 
});

Vue.prototype.$http = base;

  Vue.prototype.$http.interceptors.request.use(
  config => {
      let accessToken = localStorage.getItem('token');
      if (accessToken) {
          config.headers = Object.assign({
              Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`
          }, config.headers);
      }
      return config;
  },
  error => {
      return Promise.reject(error);
  }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`vue-resource`](https://github.com/pagekit/vue-resource) for making http requests and then use [`interceptors`](https://github.com/pagekit/vue-resource/blob/develop/docs/http.md#interceptors) to modify/patch requests.

```
Vue.http.interceptors.push(function(request, next) {

  // modify method
  request.method = 'POST';

  // modify headers
  request.headers.set('X-CSRF-TOKEN', 'TOKEN');
  request.headers.set('Authorization', 'Bearer TOKEN');

  // continue to next interceptor
  next();
});
```

Comment: Now I use Axios @Manish

Comment: Axios supports interceptors too: https://github.com/axios/axios#interceptors.

Also look into this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44207197/passing-jwt-in-headers-with-axios