# Laravel-Vue: How can I use try-catch block to catch validation exception in Validation Requests?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, vue.js, axios

I'm using vue.js. I'm hitting my server with axios like:

```
            try{
                const resp  = await axios.post('storeProduct', data, 
                            {
                                headers : header(state)
                            });
                console.log(resp);              

            }catch(error){
                console.log("you are at error");
                console.log(error);


           }
```

Here, I'm console logging the error where I get error 422 but I want to get the `message` as well. If I use try catch in a simple `validation` it works. But cant make it working with the `Validation Request object`.

In my Controller: 'ProductRequest' is the validation object which has validation rules. It gives me the errors but can't catch in the try-block of `axios` in vue.

```
 public function storeProduct(ProductRequest $request){

        try{
            return $controller->saveProducts($request);
        }catch(\Exception $e){
            return  $e;
        }

    }
```

`ProductRequest.php`

```
public function rules()
    {
        try{
            return validation_value('add_products');
        }catch(\Exception $e){
            return $e;
        }
    }
```

Is there anyway that I could return the error message from here and catch it in my 'vue axios try/catch block'

Comment: If the server returns an exception this will probably be a 500 code, so you can do `axios.post('storeProduct', data).catch(...)`.

Comment: I want to get the `422` validation error. I'm getting it on my network but cannot catch it on my `catch`. I'm catching the `422` error but not catching the validation error message.

Comment: You should not be using `try catch` in this case and you don't need the await if you use the axios promise.

Comment: yes axios is already a promise but in order to make code shorter I used await... is there a problem doing that sir.. @thefallen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it like this :

```
axios.post('storeProduct', data, 
        {
            headers : header(state)
        })
  .then(response => console.log(response.data))
  .catch(error => {
    if (error.response) {
      console.log("you are at error");
      console.log(error.response);
    }
  });
```

Comment: thanks.. can you also help me with how can i set my axios header globally in vue? `{headers : {'Authorization': 'bearer' +state.token}});` I'm send header in every axios call

Comment: Take a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48002017/4881811) for the global configuration :)