# Setting Global Axios Headers in Vue 3

Tags: django, vue.js, axios, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

I am trying to use Axios to hit my backend (Django), but I am having some trouble setting my global headers to include the CSRF token in the header.

This is reaching my server:

```
import axios from "axios";

async function loadCards() {
  var instance = axios.create({
      xsrfCookieName: window.rootData.csrfToken,
      xsrfHeaderName: "X-CSRFTOKEN",
  });
  return await instance.post(window.rootData.urlpaths.loadCards, {
    'state': props.state.label,
    'filter': props.filter.label,
    'project': window.rootData.project
  })
}
```

However, I want these headers to apply to all of my internal api requests. So I thought I would establish them in a separate file:

**axios-site.js**

```
import axios from "axios";

var siteApi = axios.create({
  xsrfCookieName: window.rootData.csrfToken,
  xsrfHeaderName: "X-CSRFTOKEN",
});

export default {
    siteApi
}
```

**Vue Component**

```
import siteApi from "@/axios-site";

setup () {

    async function loadCards() {
      return await siteApi.post(window.rootData.urlpaths.loadCards, {
        'state': props.state.label,
        'filter': props.filter.label,
        'project': window.rootData.project
      })
    }

}
```

Here is the error in console:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: _axios_site__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_4__.default.post is not a function
    at _callee$ (ActionColumn.vue?ba4f:97)
    at tryCatch (runtime.js?96cf:63)
    at Generator.invoke [as _invoke] (runtime.js?96cf:293)
    at Generator.eval [as next] (runtime.js?96cf:118)
    at asyncGeneratorStep (asyncToGenerator.js?1da1:3)
    at _next (asyncToGenerator.js?1da1:25)
    at eval (asyncToGenerator.js?1da1:32)
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at eval (asyncToGenerator.js?1da1:21)
    at _loadCards (ActionColumn.vue?ba4f:80)
```

It seems something is being lost when I run it through the external file. I'm sure I am missing something obvious, but I can't seem to pinpoint it. I found another accepted answer that follows a similar logic [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48001813/best-way-to-config-global-headers-for-get-post-patch-in-vuejs), but it isn't working in my case. Is it possible that webpack is screwing things up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should export the axios instance like :

```
export default siteApi
```

then in main.js add it to `globalProperties` :

```
import siteApi from "@/axios-site";
...
app.config.globalProperties.siteApi=siteApi
```

in any child component you'll have access to that property :

```
import { getCurrentInstance } from 'vue'

const MyComponent = {
  setup() {
    const internalInstance = getCurrentInstance()

   const {siteApi}= internalInstance.appContext.config.globalProperties 

   async function loadCards() {
      return await siteApi.post(window.rootData.urlpaths.loadCards, {
        'state': props.state.label,
        'filter': props.filter.label,
        'project': window.rootData.project
      })
    }
  }
}
```

in options api like mounted hook :

```
mounted(){
   this.siteApi.post(...)
}
```